# 4.1 sound system not working in 16.04 lts

Tags: sound

My 4.1 creative sound system (2 stereo connector) is not working in Ubuntu 16.04lts.

My system displays only 2 speakers on start, left and right, then I made small change in `/pulse/daemon.conf` file:

- Changed channels '2' to '5'
- Added "lme" in channel mapping

After that, my system takes my 4 speakers except sub woofer. The woofer and rear speaker sound interchanges when adjusting channel mixing and lfe mixing (sub woofer and rear speakers not working at same time).

How can I fix this issue?